# Angular 2 unused Class

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, typescript, angular2

Разбираю примеры на сайте документации https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html
И не получается подключить компонент `app/click-me.component.ts` 
Вот код который я ввел в `app/click-me.component.ts`  :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'click-me',
    template: `
    <button (click)="onClickMe()">Click me!</button>
    {{clickMessage}}`
})

export class ClickMeComponent {
    clickMessage = '';
    onClickMe() {
    this.clickMessage = 'You are my hero!';
    }
}
```

И подключил в `index.html`  селектор `<click-me></click-me>`
Тем не менее ничего не произошло, и в добавок класс `ClickMeComponent` подсвечивается как не активен, а ide пишет что он unused.
Так же в `main.ts` добавил `import  { ClickMeComponent } from  './click-me.component';`  и эта строка тоже светится как не активна.

Comment: Посмотрите на начальный проект на планкере: https://plnkr.co/edit/7gr7te6iTXP9zq57oytm
Если отталкиваться от этого проекта вам надо добавить `<click-me></click-me>` в шаблон компонента `App` и не забыть прописать свой компонент в поле `directives`

Answer (score 1):

- Обязательно Компоненту перед использованием прописать в directives.
- Корневую компоненту надо инициализировать через Bootstrap

Покажите как выглядит index.html